# stop opening the default browser menu on long press in mobile using angular js

Tags: javascript, angular

There is anchor tag in the mobile. when long press the anchor tag i need to show a tooltip. but suddenly browser's menu is opening. How to stop opening the browser menu, when long press the anchor tab in angular js.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appLongPress]'
})

export class LongPressDirective {
    @Output() longPress = new EventEmitter<void>();
    private timeoutId: any;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

    @HostListener('touchstart', ['$event'])
    onTouchStart(event: TouchEvent) {
        this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            this.longPress.emit();
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default action
            event.stopPropagation();
        }, 500); // Adjust the duration as needed
    }

    @HostListener('touchend')
    onTouchEnd() {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also prevent the opening of the context menu:

```
    @HostListener('contextmenu', ['$event'])
    onContextMenu(event: MouseEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

(yes it is a MouseEvent not a TouchEvent)